# Getting property from observable in a component

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable, angular7

I am trying to return a property with an **observable** within the component. I can successfully retrieve the property in the template but I do not need it there:

```
{{(selectedOrder$ | async).orderNumber}}
```

It correctly shows the order number in the template.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
this.selectedOrder$.pipe(select(order=> {
    this.selectedOrderNumber$ = order.orderNumber;
}));
```

For some reason, that returns a **404 error** when I launch my application.

Answer (score 1):

If `selectedOrder$` is the `Observable`, you have to subscribe to it in order to recover the value within the component:

```
this.selectedOrder$.subscribe(order => {
  this.selectedOrderNumber$ = order.orderNumber;
}));
```

Comment: Issue is, I am moving away from subscribing so I can just async pipe the data in. I might just look into creating a new selector for that item. Thanks for your response though. I appreciate it.

Comment: If you only need the data in the template, use an async pipe. If you need the data in the code (and optionally in the template), subscribe.